# StackExchange.Redis - How can I change configuration at runtime?

Tags: c#, configuration, redis, runtime, stackexchange.redis

Basically, I have a ["DON'T DO THIS"](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) Sentinel scenario. Because Sentinel is not safe in such scenario, I've implemented the following

```
var main   = "192.168.XXX.YY:6379,abortConnect=false";
var backup = "192.168.XXX.YY:6379,abortConnect=false";

IConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(main);

redis.ConnectionFailed += (src, args) =>
{
    if ((src as ConnectionMultiplexer).Configuration != backup) {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
            writer.Write(backup);

            (src as ConnectionMultiplexer).Configure(writer);
            /**
              * Just for checking. It does not save
              **/
            (src as ConnectionMultiplexer).GetDatabase().StringSet("aaa", "bbb");
        }
    }
};
```

So, when my main connection is down, I change the configuration, by calling *(src as ConnectionMultiplexer).Configure(writer)*, so that ConnectionMultiplexer can use the new configuration. However, ConnectionMultiplexer continue to use the old one.

Question: How can I change ConnectionMultiplexer.configuration in the ConnectionFailed event ?

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs) of the library, it seems there is no desired functionality. There is internal method Reconfigure, but it tries to connect to other servers from the configuration.

I would suggest you to refactor, if your application is not very large. Make a wrapper over ConnectionMultiplexer, pass wrapper to objects where the connection is used. We do wrap method GetConnection, which returns all the links on a single object. All who need the connection will call this method, no needs to store connection.  Inside the wrapper OnFailed subscribe to an event handler to create a new connection to a Backup.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that would be acceptable, not exactly switching the config but more like rebuilding the multiplixer

```
private static Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer> _redisMux = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(CreateMultiplexer);
public static IConnectionMultiplexer Multiplexer { get { return _redisMux.Value; } }

private const string Main   = "192.168.XXX.YY:6379,abortConnect=false";
private const string Backup = "192.168.XXX.YY:6379,abortConnect=false";

private static string ActiveConfig = Main;

private static ConnectionMultiplexer CreateMultiplexer()
{
    var mux = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ActiveConfig));
    mux.ConnectionFailed += OnConnectionFailed;

    return mux;
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
private static void OnConnectionFailed(object sender, ConnectionFailedEventArgs e)
{
    ActiveConfig = Backup;

    try { Multiplexer.Dispose(); } catch { }
    _redisMux = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(CreateMultiplexer);
}
```

Comment: The most obvious answer, but I need to retain the same instance because it is spread all over the app. Maybe an event could notify all of subscribers, but some pieces of my app cannot change their original behavior, including the reference of the ConnectionMultiplexer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I was sort of expecting your comment  .. I am trying to do something similar and I am getting to a point where I think the app should have a pointer to the Database not to the Multiplixer and I am working on this refactoring ...If I will get somewhere with the safe reconfigure and reconnect, I will share .. Question though, have you tried having both hosts in the connection string and see if the maultiplixer can handle the fail to connect scenario?

Comment: If I set both connections, I'll end up on the issue of multiple masters. In such case, StackExchange.redis uses the concept of TieBreaker to resolve the "main" master. I'm not sure whether such functionality can solve my issue safely. I'll check on monday.

Comment: @IsmailHawayel Ever get anywhere?  I'm just looking to make it possible to change redis creds/connection info and not require manually restarting every deployed application that uses redis to be restarted, I'd like to just change the one configuration place that holds connection info and all sites would update automatically without a deployment.

Comment: @IsmailHawayel Actually I figured something out with replacing the IDistributedCache singleton and using a Polly fallback policy.