# Getting an StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase from an StackExchange.Redis.RedisCache that supports configuration change at run time

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I wanted my `RedisCacheOptions` settings to be updatable at runtime if I modified the `IConfiguration` source instead of having to republish/restart the website.

With ideas from these two questions:

[Changing RedisCacheOptions after registering the StackExchangeRedisCache middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69181981/changing-rediscacheoptions-after-registering-the-stackexchangerediscache-middlew)
[StackExchange.Redis - How can I change configuration at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684346/stackexchange-redis-how-can-i-change-configuration-at-runtime?rq=3)

I came up with the following solution that wraps a `RedisCache` and watches for `RedisConnectionException` on all the `IDistributedCache` overloads and updates the configuration and retries one time:

```cs
public class UpdatableRedisService : IDistributedCache, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private RedisCache redisCache;
    private readonly IAsyncPolicy asyncPolicy;
    private readonly ISyncPolicy syncPolicy;
    private RedisCacheOptions? redisCacheOptions = null;

    public UpdatableRedisService( IConfiguration configuration )
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        EnsureRedisOptions();
        redisCache = new RedisCache( Options.Create( redisCacheOptions! ) );

        asyncPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<RedisConnectionException>()
            .RetryAsync( ( _, _ ) =>
            {
                if ( EnsureRedisOptions() )
                {
                    redisCache?.Dispose();
                    redisCache = new RedisCache( Options.Create( redisCacheOptions! ) );
                }
            } );
        
        syncPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<RedisConnectionException>()
            .Retry( ( _, _ ) =>
            {
                if ( EnsureRedisOptions() )
                {
                    redisCache?.Dispose();
                    redisCache = new RedisCache( Options.Create( redisCacheOptions! ) );
                }
            } );
    }
    
    private bool EnsureRedisOptions()
    {
        var cs = new ConnectionStringSettings();
        configuration.GetSection( "TheKeep" ).GetSection( "ConnectionStrings" ).Bind( cs );

        if 
        ( 
            redisCacheOptions?.ConfigurationOptions!.ServiceName != cs.Redis!.ServiceName ||
            redisCacheOptions?.ConfigurationOptions!.Password != cs.Redis.Password ||
            redisCacheOptions?.ConfigurationOptions!.DefaultDatabase != cs.Redis.DefaultDatabase ||
            redisCacheOptions?.ConfigurationOptions!.AllowAdmin != cs.Redis.AllowAdmin ||
            string.Join( ",", 
                redisCacheOptions?.ConfigurationOptions!.EndPoints.Select( e => e.ToString() ) ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>() 
            ) != string.Join( ",", cs.Redis.Endpoints.Select( e => "Unspecified/" + e ) )
        )
        {
            var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                ServiceName = cs.Redis!.ServiceName,
                Password = cs.Redis.Password,
                DefaultDatabase = cs.Redis.DefaultDatabase,
                CommandMap = CommandMap.Default,
                AllowAdmin = cs.Redis.AllowAdmin
            };

            foreach ( var endpoint in cs.Redis!.Endpoints )
            {
                configurationOptions.EndPoints.Add( endpoint );
            }

            redisCacheOptions = new RedisCacheOptions
            {
                InstanceName = "camelot-redis",
                ConfigurationOptions = configurationOptions
            };

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Dispose() => redisCache.Dispose();

    public byte[]? Get( string key ) => syncPolicy.Execute<byte[]?>( () => redisCache.Get( key ) );
    public Task<byte[]?> GetAsync( string key, CancellationToken token = default ) => asyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync<byte[]?>( () => redisCache.GetAsync( key, token ) );
    public void Refresh( string key ) => syncPolicy.Execute( () => redisCache.Refresh( key ) );
    public Task RefreshAsync( string key, CancellationToken token = default ) => asyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync( () => redisCache.RefreshAsync( key, token ) );
    public void Remove( string key ) => syncPolicy.Execute( () => redisCache.Remove( key ) );
    public Task RemoveAsync( string key, CancellationToken token = default ) => asyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync( () => redisCache.RemoveAsync( key, token ) );
    public void Set( string key, byte[] value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options ) => syncPolicy.Execute( () => redisCache.Set( key, value, options ) );
    public Task SetAsync( string key, byte[] value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token = default ) => asyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync( () => redisCache.SetAsync( key, value, options, token ) );
}
```

So instead of using `builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache()`, as I was before to configure the connection settings, of course I registered this as so:

```cs
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.Add( ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IDistributedCache, UpdatableRedisService>() );
```

In some environments, we have sential Redis connections and others we have 'regular' single database connections (forgive me for terminology if wrong, I'm no Redis expert).

The problem is, we have a web farm for the web site, so I wanted to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AddDataProtection` and store the keys in the Redis database so that whichever server was handling the web request, it could correctly decode/decrypt the cookies passed to the server.  Otherwise, I was receiving:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {02ae4a00-1dcd-424e-aac5-a0b0cb38d60d} was not found in the key ring.

I was using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis package and its `PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis` method and at first, I wanted to figure out how to get an `IDatabase` from a `RedisCache`, and without reflection, I didn't see how this was possible.

**Is there a path I can take to get `PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis` called correctly and create an `IDatabase` via the `databaseFactory` delegate leveraging my `UpdatableRedisService`?  Or a better way to implement an 'updatable RedisCache'?**

As it currently stands, I have done the following.  Of course, this is only called one time at site startup, so if any of the settings change, I have to restart the site, which defeats the purpose of my `UpdatableRedisService` class.

```cs
// This breaks UpdatableRedisService goal because the connection strings are only read one time
// at startup, so if credentials or information is changed, the application/site will need to be
// restarted/republished for new settings to work correctly.
builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(
    () =>
    {
        var cs = new Domain.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings();
        builder.Configuration.GetSection( "TheKeep" ).GetSection( "ConnectionStrings" ).Bind( cs );

        var configurationOptions = new StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions
        {
            ServiceName = cs.Redis!.ServiceName,
            Password = cs.Redis.Password,
            DefaultDatabase = cs.Redis.DefaultDatabase,
            CommandMap = StackExchange.Redis.CommandMap.Default,
            AllowAdmin = cs.Redis.AllowAdmin
        };
        foreach ( var endpoint in cs.Redis!.Endpoints )
        {
            configurationOptions.EndPoints.Add( endpoint );
        }

        var redis = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect( configurationOptions );
        return redis.GetDatabase();
    },
    "DataProtection-Keys"
);
```